# Unit testing Angular Router queryParamMap

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, url-parameters

I am looking to utilize [Angular queryParamMap](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#queryParamMap) in ngOnInit lifecycle. The goal is to pass queryparam from this component as state to another. Although functionality works like charm, I am unable to unit test the code functionality.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private readonly route: Router, private router: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.queryParamMap.subscribe((resp) => {
      
    const state ={} as any;
    state.token = resp.get('token')
    state.clientID = resp.get('id')
    state.timestamp = resp.get('timeStamp')
      
      this.route.navigate(['/dashboard'],{state})
    });
  }}
```

And this is my unit test approach with jest

```
const activatedRouteMock = {
    queryParamMap: of(routes:{token:1,id:2},
    test(key){
return this.routes.key
})
  };



const mockRoute = mock<Router>();
```

when I do

```
it('should be defined', () => {
    component.ngOnInit()
expect(mockRoute.navigate).toBeCalledTimes(1)
expect(mockRoute.navigate).toBeCalledWith(['dashboard'], {state:{token:1,id:2}})
});
```

But I get error as

> Expected call 1
> Received call 0

I am not sure on how do I unit test this functionality with QueryParamMap as the properties could be null.

Comment: Check out `RouterTestingModule`

Comment: @Antoniossss My problem is unit test does nothing past `subscribe`. 

 I tried console logging after subscribe but just doesn't log at all.

Comment: Provide complete test config. No idea hownyour setuo look alike

Comment: Anwy why route is a Router and router is ActivatedRoute is a mistery to me

Comment: Clean your code, provide complete example and dont assume that you know which parts are important  to the case and which are not. Just include it whole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I'm using Jest to implement my tests.

My component constructor and ngOnInit methods look like this:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe((params) => {
        this.partner = params.get('partner')
    }
}
```

Then on the test file I create a params object with a mock get function and apply this setup on beforeEach methods:

```
const params = {
    get: jest.fn()
}

describe('MyComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [RouterTestingModule],
            declarations: [MyComponent],
            providers: [{
                provide: ActivatedRoute,
                useValue: {
                    queryParamMap: of(params)
                }
            }]
        })
    )

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent)
        component = fixture.componentInstance
        fixture.detectChanges()
        TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute)
    )
}
```

And in my test case I spy on the `get` function of my `params` mocked object, because I set in the provider to return this object inside an observable for the `ActivatedRoute.queryParamMap`:

```
it('should set the partner property to PARTNER_X as in the GET parameter', () => {
      const getParamSpy = jest.spyOn(params, 'get').mockReturnValueOnce('PARTNER_X')
  
      component.ngOnInit()

      expect(component.partner).toBe('PARTNER_X')
      expect(getParamSpy).toBeCalledWith('partner')
})
```

To get more specific answers it's better to provide more details about your setup, otherwise it's hard to identify what is the problem you may be  facing.

I hope this could be useful.

Comment: I did exactly the same, forgot to update the solution. So I am marking your answer as correct.